# Having a QScrollArea dynamically fit its parent but does not expand for its children

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea

I seem to be having an issue with getting the behavior I want from a `QScrollArea`. As it stands, whenever I add something to the layout of the widget set as the target of the scroll area it will rather opt to expand the entire window rather than fit to scroll.

Here's my current setup:

```
QSplitter * mainArea = new QSplitter( Qt::Vertical );

QWidget * containment = new QWidget;
containment->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout );

currentStructures = new QWidget;
currentStructures->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout );
currentStructures->layout()->setAlignment( Qt::AlignTop );

QScrollArea * scroll = new QScrollArea();
scroll->setWidget( currentStructures );

containment->layout()->addWidget( currentStructures );
mainArea->addWidget( containment );

mainArea->addWidget( new QWidget ); //TODO: create preview bar

this->layout()->addWidget( mainArea );
```

This makes it so that the scroll area only ever expands and never shows the scroll bars.

By inserting this line:

```
containment->setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Ignored );
```

I can get the area to ignore the size of its children but it also doesn't take up the space needed nor does it show scroll bars -- it just crunches the widget inside of it.

I'm a bit of a greenhorn to using Qt, but I was wondering how I would achieve the behavior that I need: I would like the scroll area to greedily take up the area it has available from its parent layout but not expand the the containing layouts vertically when adding but instead actually shows scroll bars. I'm planning on allowing a lot of resizing, so it needs to actually scale to the parent instead of just being a fixed size. I am at a loss as to how I should proceed in solving this aspect of my GUI. Thank you for your time.

If you would like to tackle this problem visually, here's a harness that you can use. I greatly appreciate your help.

```
#include <QtWidgets\qapplication.h>
#include <QtWidgets\qsplitter.h>
#include <QtWidgets\qlayout.h>
#include <QtWidgets\qscrollarea.h>
#include <QtWidgets\qpushbutton.h>
#include <QtWidgets\qlabel.h>
#include <QtWidgets\qsizepolicy.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QWidget * testWidget = new QWidget;
    testWidget->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout );

    //////////////////CODE IN QUESTIION//////////////////////
    QSplitter * mainArea = new QSplitter( Qt::Vertical );

    QWidget * containment = new QWidget;
    containment->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout );

    //containment->setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Ignored );

    QWidget * currentStructures = new QWidget;
    currentStructures->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout );
    currentStructures->layout()->setAlignment( Qt::AlignTop );

    QScrollArea * scroll = new QScrollArea();
    scroll->setWidget( currentStructures );

    containment->layout()->addWidget( currentStructures );
    mainArea->addWidget( containment );
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    QPushButton * pushIntoLayout = new QPushButton( "Add Element to Widget" );
    QWidget::connect( pushIntoLayout, &QPushButton::clicked, [currentStructures](){ currentStructures->layout()->addWidget( new QLabel( "A generated label" ) ); } );
    mainArea->addWidget( pushIntoLayout );
    currentStructures->setStyleSheet(
        "QWidget {"
            "background-color: #FAA;"
        "}" 
    );


    testWidget->layout()->addWidget( mainArea );

    testWidget->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide testing code, can't repeat your problem.

Comment: Sure, I'll make a quick and concise test case and append the question soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even after copying and pasting my code to make a test harness I had not noticed my grievous error. I had mistakenly pushed the `currentStructures` widget to the container's layout rather than `scroll`, the scrolling area after giving it its child.

An excerpt from the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/) on [`void QScrollArea::setWidget( QWidget * widget )`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#setWidget)  for those unfamiliar:

> The widget becomes a child of the scroll area, and will be destroyed when the scroll area is deleted or when a new widget is set.

Thanks to everyone who looked it over.

For those wondering, the fixed code would look like the following:

```
QSplitter * mainArea = new QSplitter( Qt::Vertical );

QWidget * containment = new QWidget;
containment->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout );

QWidget * currentStructures = new QWidget;
currentStructures->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout );
currentStructures->layout()->setAlignment( Qt::AlignTop );

QScrollArea * scroll = new QScrollArea();
scroll->setWidget( currentStructures );
scroll->setWidgetResizable( true );

containment->layout()->addWidget( scroll );
mainArea->addWidget( containment );

mainArea->addWidget( new QWidget ); //TODO: create preview bar

this->layout()->addWidget( mainArea );
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem ! That frustrated me a LOT !